# Sqlite3 tables not visible

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running a Flask app and trying to develop an authentication system for which I am using a sqlite3 database. I am defining the database schema in the code and then trying to create the table. I have added the **app_context()** according to the documentation but upon running the command in the sqlite3 shell, no tables are coming up

In the Python shell I ran this code:

```
from app import db
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

**After checking, no tables are being created. I also tried to do it using the flask shell, but still, the tables are not visible**

The code I use for viewing tables:

```
sqlite3 database.db
.tables
```

**Finally, this is the main code in the flask app**:

[image: flask code]

Comment: You're creating the database before you've defined any models!

Comment: I don't understand. What do I have to do here?